# Excel 2011 cannot execute a function in cell

Tags: excel

I am using MAC 2011 Excel (version 14.4.2)
When I input a function    =IF(B5=B6,B5, " ")

[image]

but when i press enter, instead of giving me the result, the cell show

```
=IF(B5=B6,B5, " ")
```

What am I mising?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean that your cells are showing formulas instead of the values produced by the formulas you can find an option in the Formulas tab to turn this off/on. I'm on PC where is looks like the following:

[image: Show Formulas]

Obviously it will differ slightly on a Mac OS.

Answer (score 0):

When I usually see this, the cell is formatted as Text.

1. Clear all formats from the cell

[image]

2. Force Excel to look at cell contents again by either

   a. Find-Replacing all "=" with "=" or

   b. Entering cell editing and immediately leaving

[source](https://ion.icaew.com/itcounts/b/weblog/posts/exceltipoftheweek53causesofformulasnotcalculating)